# AWS Database Failover with external Tools like Tableau

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, failover

Whilst I get how a Web Application set up with AWS using an ELB can access a Standby DB in case of AZ failure, how does that work if using reporting via Tableau not in AWS or some other product using JDBC to connect to that AWS DB?

How does the re-direct occur automatically from the Master to StandBy DB in another AZ?

- Do we need an ELB also for external reporting tools access, when not running in AWS themselves?

Comment: What do you use for db? Aurora? Rds? Self hosting on ec2?

Comment: @user3100287 was just generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rds and Aurora use DNS failover.
As long as you have multiAZ enabled, the failover is handled by AWS at the DNS level. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html